# Unmarshal XML preserving child elements

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

Code at http://play.golang.org/p/PlOMw4wfT2

I'd like to preserve the child elements in some XML tag when unmarshalling. This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    xmltext := []byte(`<Root><Foo>text text text <a href="url">foo bar</a> and more text.</Foo></Root>`)
    type mystruct struct {
        Foo string `xml:",innerxml"`
    }
    v := &mystruct{}

    err := xml.Unmarshal(xmltext, v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(v.Foo)
}
```

and the result is:

```
    <Foo>text text text <a href="url">foo bar</a> and more text.</Foo>
```

but I'd like to get

```
    text text text <a href="url">foo bar</a> and more text.
```

(without the surrounding Foo-tags)

That is: I want to preserve the "string value" (not the string value in the XPath sense) of the element Foo.

How can I get the contents from the element Foo without the `<Foo>` and `</Foo>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `,innerxml` contains the contents of the XML tag (that's what it's name is about). Therefore I have to go one level deeper:

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    xmltext := []byte(`<Root><Foo>text text text <a href="url">foo bar</a> and more text.</Foo></Root>`)

    type text struct {
        Text string `xml:",innerxml"`
    }
    type mystruct struct {
        Foo text
    }
    v := &mystruct{}

    err := xml.Unmarshal(xmltext, v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(v.Foo.Text)
    // text text text <a href="url">foo bar</a> and more text.
}
```